# Bottom up Splay trees vs Top down splay trees

Tags: splay-tree

I'm trying to learn more about Splay trees but there is very little information to be found online about the difference between Top-down splay trees and Bottom up splay trees. Can anyone tell me what's the difference between Top-down and bottom up splay trees? Is one type better than the other?